# Why aren't Inf, -Inf and NaN keywords in Python?

Tags: python, ieee-754

In [PEP 754](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0754/#id5)'s rejection notice, it's stated that:

> This PEP has been rejected. After sitting open for four years, it has
>   failed to generate sufficient community interest.
>
> Several ideas of this PEP were implemented for Python 2.6.
>   float('inf') and repr(float('inf')) are now guaranteed to work on
>   every supported platform with IEEE 754 semantics. However the
>   eval(repr(float('inf'))) roundtrip is still not supported unless you
>   define inf and nan yourself:
>
> ```
> >>> inf = float('inf')
> >>> inf, 1E400
> (inf, inf)
> >>> neginf = float('-inf')
> >>> neginf, -1E400
> (-inf, -inf)
> >>> nan = float('nan')
> >>> nan, inf * 0.
> (nan, nan)
> ```

This would seem to say there is no native support for Inf, NaN and -Inf in Python, and the example provided is accurate! But, it is needlessly verbose:

```
$ python2.7
>>> 1e400
inf
>>> 1e400 * 0
nan
>>> -1e400 * 0
nan
>>> -1e400
-inf
$ python3
>>> 1e400
inf
>>> 1e400 * 0
nan
>>> -1e400 * 0
nan
>>> -1e400
-inf
```

These are **canonical** representations of the number 1 * 10 ^ 400. The names `inf` and `nan` do not exist in the grammar by default, but if they are there in the representation then why aren't `inf` and `nan` keywords?

I am not asking why the PEP was rejected as that is opinion-based.

Comment: There are [very few keywords](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords)   in Python. `float`, for example, isn't a keyword. Certainly `float` is more generally useful than `inf`. Why then *should* `inf` be a keyword?

Comment: @Robᵩ `float` and `int` happen to be builtins that are both types and functions; they are special. Why not `nan` if it exists?

Comment: Because people use `inf` and `nan` rarely, so they don't warrant the status of being keywords?

Comment: I mean, most of my Python programming involves integers, strings, dicts, and file I/O. I rarely even touch floating-point in any of my work.

Comment: @Nayuki that's a very good point, I guess Python doesn't have a overload of keywords *cough* Perl 6

Comment: @Nayuki Well, that's probably because floats in Python are a tedious job

Comment: It's hard to add a keyword after the fact; someone out there may be using your proposed keyword as a variable name, and that change will break their code. Is it worth that risk to define a constant very few people will care about?

Comment: Though by comparison, in JavaScript `Infinity` and `NaN` are global variables (properties of the `window` object), so they are "effectively" keywords.

Comment: @chepner This was proposed back in 2.6! Look, now 3.5-3.7 are making `async` and `await` keywords, along with 3.x's other keywords

Comment: I said it is hard, not impossible. In the case of simplifying asynchronous code, the benefits were judged to outweigh the drawbacks. No one seems to think the same is true of `nan` and `inf`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that no one wanted to clutter the namespace needlessly.

If you want to do math, you can still do:

```
import math

print(math.inf)
print(-math.inf)
print(math.nan)
```

Output:

```
inf
-inf
nan
```

Comment: But the output is not a printed string, it's what I showed in the question -- they're natively supported but not keywords.

Comment: Define "natively supported". The values returned by a `repr` call don't necessarily have any special internal meaning to Python. For example, `"nan"` is created via an ordinary [strcopy call](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/513f40a9abfc00b7de1f36eb780c2cf47169cf2a/Python/pystrtod.c#L832) shortly before repr finishes executing.

Answer (score -2):

you can use

float('inf')

np.nan